# C# Mysql LINQ - Expressions LINQ to Entities does not recognize method ToList

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have a query:

```
var query = (from persons in _entity.Persons
                         where persons.Id == personId select new Person
                         {
                             PersonId = (int)persons.Id,
                             PersonName = persons.PersonName,
                             PersonLastName = persons.PersonLastName,
                             PersonPatronymic = persons.PersonPatronymic,

                             PersonSigns = new PersonSigns()
                             {
                                  BodyType = _entity.PersonsSignsBodyType
                                                           .Where(c => c.PersonId == persons.Id)
                                                           .AsEnumerable()
                                                           .Select(c => c.PersonBodyType).ToList()
                             }
                        });
query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

When you run a query throws an exception:

> "Expressions LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method"
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.Nullable`1 [System.Int32]]
>   ToList [Nullable`1] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [System.
>   Nullable`1 [System.Int32]]) ", so it can not be transformed into an
>   expression of the repository."

But when I remove this part of the code - it works:

```
PersonSigns = new PersonSigns()
{
      BodyType = _entity.PersonsSignsBodyType
                        .Where(c => c.PersonId == persons.Id)
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(c => c.PersonBodyType).ToList()
}
```

The fact that a person may have a few distinguishing features of the body, so you need to take all the IDs and the special body will be placed in the list.

**Q:** How do I rewrite the inner query?

Comment: remove the .AsEnumerable() and try. Also, before .Tolist() use .FirstOrDefault() i.e. .Select(c => c.PersonBodyType).FirstOrDefault().ToList()

Comment: try this `.Where(c => c.PersonId.Value == persons.Id)`

Comment: Nothing helps. I had to change property type "BodyType" with List<int> on IEnumerable<int>. And it worked! Thanks for answers/